# How I add to a list same number multiple times by count?

Tags: python, list, prime-factoring

I've got 2 problems here.

my first problem is that the code shows me only one time a factor even though it's multiple x times by the same factor. I don't know how to add it to the factor list.

Another problem is I'm not sure in print - how the sep works and how can I write "*" only between elements of factor list.

I can't use any import functions here (intertools, maths etc.)

Please help me.

```
def factorize(n):
    prvocisla = []
    faktor = []
    #prime numbers
    for num in range(1, 2000):
       if num > 1:
           for i in range(2, num):
               if (num % i) == 0:
                   break
           else:
               prvocisla.append(num)
    count = 0           
    for i in prvocisla:
        if n % i == 0:
            count += 1
            faktor.append(i)
    print(n, " =", *faktor , sep=' *', end='\n')
    
factorize(360)

My result:
360 * = *2 *3 *5

The right result:
360 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5
```

I try the count function with adding same factor to the list "count times" but it shows me an Error.

Comment: Use recursion. Divide the number by the factor. Then get all the factors of the result, and add this factor to that list. Keep repeating until you get to 1.

Comment: For the output, something like `'*'.join(faktor)`

Comment: Your second loop only looks at each prime factor once, and so only prints each prime factor once, even though 2 is actually a factor three times.

Comment: For the `print` try this *f-string*:  `print(f"{n!s} = {' * '.join(str(k) for k in faktor)}")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your second 'for' loop you evaluate if there is a prime number in your number, but not how many times it is present.

To do this you need to repeat the cycle every time you find a prime number and divide the initial number by the prime number. this way you will get to 1 and get all the factors in the array.

Here the right code:

```
def factorize(n):
    prvocisla = []
    faktor = []
    #prime numbers
    for num in range(1, 2000):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                prvocisla.append(num)
    count = 0  

    t = n    # <-- a temporary variable which get n value
    while t>1:
        for i in prvocisla:
            if t % i == 0:
                count += 1
                faktor.append(i)
                t = t/i    <-- divide t every time you find a factor
                break

    print(f"{n!s} = {' * '.join(str(k) for k in faktor)}")

factorize(360)
```

For the print I use the @CreepyRaccoon suggestion.